# How to add task list when new project created via webhooks

Tags: activecollab

Have been playing around with the zapier integration but can't figure out how to get the functionality I'm looking for.  Looking for help.

Basically, this is what I am trying to achieve

- When a new project is created (Project A), it gets added as a Task List in Project X and all tasks lists and tasks from Project A are added as subtasks to the task list in Project X

Looking to automate this via Zapier / webhooks but can't figure it out yet.

Any ideas?

Trying to create one mast project, which has all projects inside of it for better clarity overall as the existing project timeline report becomes hard to use when there are 20+ projects running at once.

Thanks in advance.